Is there a way to draw my tilemap once instead of every frame?
My game runs at seconds per frame when I draw my tilemap to gamepanel, as it does it every frame and just clogs up. I'll include some code of the tile, map and panel classes. Hopefully, someone can help.
What I would like is for a way to create the map and display it once, with everything else updating on top of it. I am new to Java and came from writing games in pygame (which is odd as I thought I'd have more issues like this with Python due to GIL)
First the GamePanel class.
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import entity.Player;

import tile.TileMap;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    // Screen Settings
    public final int tileSize = 25;
    public final int maxScreenColumn = 26;
    public final int maxScreenRow = 18;

    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenColumn;
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;

    final int FPS = 60;

    Thread gameThread;
    
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();

    public int playerX = tileSize * 13;
    public int playerY = tileSize * 10;
    public int playerSpeed = 3;

    TileMap tileM = new TileMap(this);

    Player player = new Player(this, keyH);

    //  set player's default pos

    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
        double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;

        while (gameThread != null) {
            //  1. Update info such as character pos etc...
            update();
            //  2. Draw to the gamePanel object...
            repaint();

            try {
                double remainingTime = nextDrawTime - System.nanoTime();

                if (remainingTime < 0) {
                    remainingTime = 0;
                }

                Thread.sleep((long)remainingTime / 1000000);

                nextDrawTime += drawInterval;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        player.update();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        tileM.drawTileMap(g2);
        
        //  tile.draw(g2);

        player.draw(g2);

        g2.dispose();
    }
}

Next is the TileMap class
package tile;

import main.GamePanel;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class TileMap {

    GamePanel gp;

    public String tileMap[][] = 
        {   
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" },
            {"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G" }
        };

    public TileMap(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    public void drawTileMap (Graphics2D g2) {
        for (int col = 0; col < gp.maxScreenColumn-1; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < gp.maxScreenRow-1; row++) {
                if (tileMap[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
                    Tile tile = new Tile(gp, col*gp.tileSize, row*gp.tileSize, "/res/tiles/grass1.png");
                    tile.draw(g2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Finally the Tile class.
package tile;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.GamePanel;

public class Tile {

    private BufferedImage image;
    public boolean collision = false;

    GamePanel gp;

    int x;
    int y;

    public String path;

    public Tile (GamePanel gp, int x, int y, String path) {
        this.gp = gp;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.setImage(path);
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage () {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage (String path) {
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
            //  this.image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(path);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }

    public void draw (Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.drawImage(image, x, y, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
    }

}



You only have a single grass image. Don't read the image every time you create a Tile. Read the tile once and pass it as a parameter. 2)  Don't invoke drawTileMap in the paintComponent() method. Instead create a BufferedImage of the TileMap once. Then in the paintComponent method you simply paint the BufferedImage of the entire TileMap.


First and foremost:  Reading from a file or .jar entry every single time you draw a frame is slowing down the program.  A lot.  Instead of doing that, create each of your Tile objects once.
private Tile[][] tiles;

public TileMap(GamePanel gp) {
    this.gp = gp;

    int rowCount = tileMap.length;
    int columnCount = tileMap[0].length;

    tiles = new Tile[][rowCount];
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        tiles[row] = new Tile[columnCount];
        for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
            if (tileMap[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
                tiles[row][col] =
                    new Tile(gp, col*gp.tileSize, row*gp.tileSize,
                        "/res/tiles/grass1.png");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void drawTileMap(Graphics2D g2) {
    for (int col = 0; col < gp.maxScreenColumn-1; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < gp.maxScreenRow-1; row++) {
            Tile tile = tiles[row][col];
            if (tile != null) {
                tile.draw(g2);
            }
        }
    }
}

Secondly, get rid of this entire method:
public void run() {

AWT and Swing don't work like that.  They operate on one and only one thread, a special system-created thread known as the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.  You cannot perform AWT/Swing operations on any other thread.  Doing so will either behave strangely (meaning, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn’t), or will throw an exception.
Instead, use the javax.swing.Timer class (not the java.util.Timer class) to run something at regular intervals:
public void startGameThread() {
    Timer updateTimer = new Timer(1000 / FPS,
        e -> {
            update();
            repaint();
        });
    updateTimer.start();
}

Third, do not call dispose() on a Graphics or Graphics2D object unless you created that object yourself.  The Graphics object passed to paintComponent does not belong to you;  it was created by Swing, and only Swing may decide when to dispose of it.  So remove this line:
g2.dispose();

